# Scala: Match based on expression

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have some scala code with which I'd like to use scala's pattern matching. What the code does is get a class's public getters and add the method name as the json key and the method value as the json value (serializing it if it's an object or array). Here's the code:

```
private def serialize(any: Any): JsonObject = {
  val json = new JsonObject()
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val accessors = rm.classSymbol(any.getClass).toType.members.collect {
    case m: MethodSymbol if m.isGetter && m.isPublic => m
  }
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(any)
  for (accessor <- accessors) {
    val key = properCase(accessor.name.toString)
    val value = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(accessor).apply()
    if (accessor.returnType <:< typeOf[String]) 
      json.addProperty(key, value.asInstanceOf[String])
    else if (accessor.returnType <:< typeOf[Character]) 
      json.addProperty(key, value.asInstanceOf[Character])
    else if (accessor.returnType <:< typeOf[Boolean]) 
      json.addProperty(key, value.asInstanceOf[Boolean])
    else if (accessor.returnType <:< typeOf[Number]) 
      json.addProperty(key, value.asInstanceOf[Number])
    else if (accessor.returnType <:< typeOf[Iterable[Any]]) 
      json.add(key, serialize(value.asInstanceOf[Iterable[Any]]))
    else
       json.add(key, serialize(value.asInstanceOf[Any]))
  }
  json
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
accessors match {
  case _.returnType <:< typeOf[String] => json.addProperty(
      properCase(key.name.toString), 
      instanceMirror.reflectMethod(accessor).apply().asInstanceOf[String])
  ...
}
```

However, the compiler is very unhappy with that, saying that `'=>' expected but '.' found`. I assume that the compiler isn't expecting an expression in the match statement and wants a constant (just as in java). Is there any way to use scala's match style syntax with an expression?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JeanLogeart I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a test in pattern-matching, write

```
case x if x.returnType <:< typeOf[String] => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get about halfway there as follows:

```
accessors.foreach { accessor =>
  val key = properCase(accessor.name.toString)
  val value = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(accessor).apply()
  value match {
    case s: String => json.addProperty(key, s);
    case c: Character => json.addProperty(key, c);
    case b: Boolean => json.addProperty(key, b);
    case n: Number => json.addProperty(key, n);
    case i: Iterable[Any] => json.add(key, serialize(i))
    case _ => json.add(key, serialize(value))
  }
}
```

Although, this doesn't match based on an expression.